# Creating Custom Fortunes for the fortune Command

Tags: command-line

Having trouble creating custom fortunes for the fortune command. I am running Mac OS X 10.6 and I used fink to install the fortune and fortune-mod command. Here is my process:

1. I create a text file like so:

   ```
   ARMED MEN ARE CITIZENS, UNARMED MEN
   ARE SUBJECTS!!! 
   %
   Armenians are
   comical in full battle dress. % Armies
   aren't known for neatness.  -- Solomon
   Short %
   ```
2. Ran this command in the Terminal:

   ```
   strfile mytextfile quotes.dat
   ```
3. Finally I try and run:

   ```
   fortune quotes.dat
   ```

   And greets me with this error:

   ```
   fortune:/Users/bigred/Downloads/quotes.dat not a fortune file or directory
   ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You run it from the text file, the .dat file is just the database. Both files need to be named the same and in the same directory. When you type `fortune quotes` it will look for quotes.dat.

so:

```
strfile quotes
```

will create quotes.dat. You can then run them like so:

```
fortune quotes
```

output:

```
[root@awesome ~]# fortune quotes
ARMED MEN ARE CITIZENS, UNARMED MEN ARE SUBJECTS!!!
```

Comment: You're very welcome! :)